# How to find even numbers in a string in Python

Tags: python

I tried to find even numbers in a string

```
    s = "75,41,14,8,73,45,-16"
    evenNumbers = []

    for number in s.split(","):
        if int(number) % 2 == 0 and int(number) > 0:
            evenNumbers += number

    evenNumbers = ','.join(evenNumbers)
    print("Even Numbers : \"{}\"".format(evenNumbers))
```

and its output is like

```
Even Numbers : "1,4,8"
```

I want to make it like

```
Even Numbers : "14,8"
```

Comment: replace `evenNumbers += number` by `evenNumbers.append(number)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will take expected output with this. All you need to do to replace `evenNumbers += number` with `evenNumbers.append(int_num)`.

```
s = "75,41,14,8,73,45,-16"
evenNumbers = []

for number in s.split(","):
    int_num = int(number)
    if int_num % 2 == 0 and int_num > 0:
        evenNumbers.append(int_num)

print("Even Numbers : \"{}\"".format(evenNumbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add numbers, not strings to the list

```
evenNumbers += int(number)
```

Then join strings

```
evenNumbers = ','.join(map(str, evenNumbers))
```

---

Otherwise, do `evenNumbers.append(number)`

---

Or do it all on one line

```
evenNumbers = ','.join(filter(lambda x: int(x) % 2 == 0 and int(x) > 0, "75,41,14,8,73,45,-16".split(",")))
```

Comment: Making int(number) didn't worked. But I changed the type of evenNumbers to array. And then I add  evenNumbers = ','.join(map(str, evenNumbers)) . And it did work. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "changed type to array"?

Answer (score 1):

You can append the number to the list. Something like this:

```
s = "75,41,14,8,73,45,-16"
evenNumbers = []

for number in s.split(","):
    if int(number) % 2 == 0 and int(number) > 0:
        evenNumbers.append(number)

print("Even Numbers : \"{}\"".format(evenNumbers))
```

> "['14', '8']"

Comment: I need an output like : Even Numbers : "14,8"

Comment: Then you have to change the last line to this:

Comment: print("Even Numbers : {}".format(str(evenNumbers).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("'", "")))

Comment: It turns the list into a string, and replaces the unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do a list comprehensions

```
even_numbers = [n for n in s.split(',') if int(n) % 2 == 0]
```